# Wordpress wp query for custom post type category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on pagination in WordPress, pagination working fine for all posts, But I need posts based on category

Now I am using this query for getting all post

```
$per_page = 8;
$start = $page * $per_page;
$page = sanitize_text_field($_POST['page']);

$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_type = 'articles' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $start, $per_page ));
```

Can anyone tell me how to display post based on category, I am using custom post type('articles').

Thanks

Comment: do you want to display in category page?

Comment: I'd highly recommend doing advanced queries by using WP_Query https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with this that is working with me.You may help this code.

Here, you have to `join` some tables to get post based on category. For that I used `join` in query.You are using `ajax` and you will get `category_name` in `POST` and that will be assign to related table.

**Updated:**

```
$per_page = 8;
$start = $page * $per_page;
$page = sanitize_text_field($_POST['page']);

$category_name = $_POST['category_name'];

$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts   
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
WHERE $wpdb->terms.name = ''
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy LIKE '%".$category_name."%'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'articles' 
ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $start, $per_page));
```

Comment: I need some clarification above query, Let me tell you clearly what I need, I created a custom post type 'articles' and taxonomy ('articles_category'). Now I want to display the custom post based on the category, for example, if I am passing category name through ajax, how to get the posts for the particular category,  Above query post2cat and postmeta.meta_key(I didn't use this keyword before please explain this). Thank You

Comment: Thank you for correcting my answer, Please do upvote